# Example of a group with unsolvable word problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics, computational-group-theory

Today I noticed that the last relator in the 27-relator presentation
of a group with unsolvable word problem given in

> Donald J. Collins: [A simple presentation of a group with unsolvable word problem](http://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1256044631).
> *Illinois J. Math.* 30(1986), no. 2, 230-234.

is a tautology, namely $ka^{-3}ta^3 = ka^{-3}ta^3$. As the total length of
the presentation (i.e. sum of the lengths of the relators) is given in the paper
as 421, and as the other 26 relators have together length 402, I concluded that
the correct last relator would probably have length 19, provided that nothing else
is wrong. A Google search for an erratum found a proposed corrected relator
$a^{-3}ta^3k = ka^{-3}ta^3$ [here](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/%7Ewclark/algctlg/groups.html) (see Section *Decision problems*).
However this relator has length 16, and thus the presentation has then total length 418
rather than 421.

> **Question:** Have I miscounted something, or is there still something more wrong
> with the presentation in the paper?

Comment: Stefan, it's not a good idea to claim an "error in a classical paper" in the title of the question, so I removed that.

Comment: Stefan: Did you consider using the earlier paper "Simple examples of groups with unsolvable word problem" by V.V. Borisov (Math. Notes 6 (1969), 768–775): Borisov has fewer defining relators (only 12). 

Comment: @Misha: Thank you! -- Though Borisov's paper appears to be behind a paywall, which is the reason why I looked at the one by Collins.

Comment: @Francois: I originally formulated the title of the question such as to be
as informative as possible. If you think there is no such error in the paper
in question, then it would be nice if you would let me know what I have
misunderstood. -- Nevertheless I do not insist on the wording of the title.


Comment: Stefan: If you are in the US, you can use the interlibrary loan to get the paper. Other (developed) countries probably have a version of the ILL as well. 

Comment: The Russian original of Borisov's paper is freely available here:
http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/mz6959

Comment: Anton: Спасибо!